# Why is $\zeta_m(s)=\prod\limits_\chi L(s,\chi).$ a Dirichlet series with positive coefficients?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

[image]

I know from this link: [$\zeta_m(s)=\prod\limits_{p\nmid m} \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{f(p)s}}\right)^{g(p)}}$ is a Dirichlet series with non-negative coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137810/zeta-ms-prod-limits-p-nmid-m-frac1-left1-frac1pfps-right) 
why $\zeta_m(s)$ is a Dirichlet series:

If $A(s)=\sum_n a_nn^{-s}, B(s) =\sum_n b_nn^{-s}$ we have

$$A(s)B(s)=\sum_n\left(\sum_{d|n}a_d b_{n/d}\right)n^{-s}$$

That is, the product of 2 Dirichlet series of the forms $A$ and $B$ is a Dirichlet series. Since $\zeta_m(s)$ is exactly such a finite product it is a Dirichlet series.

However, I do not understand how $\zeta_m(s)$ would have positive coefficients. I didn't quite get the expiation provided in the link.

Can someone care to carefully explain why $\zeta_m(s)$ would have positive coefficients? I just can't seem to see how the form of $\zeta_m(s)$ in the picture above somehow allows us to conclude that it Dirichlet Series has positive coefficients. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to see if you write it like $$\zeta_m(s) = \prod\limits_{p \nmid m}(1+p^{-f(p)s} + p^{-2 f(p)s} + \cdots)^{g(p)}$$
Let me do the special case when all the $g(p)$ are equal to $1$.  If $n$ is an integer relatively prime to $m$, write $n = \prod\limits_p p^{e_p}$ and set
$$h(n) = \sum\limits_p e_p f(p)$$
Then

$$\zeta_m(s) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N, (n,m) = 1} \frac{1}{n^{h(n)s}} $$

When the $g(p)$ are positive terms, you must expand $(1+p^{-f(p)s} + p^{-2f(p)s} + \cdots)^{g(p)}$ first before continuing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that's exactly the problem that I have. How can I conclude that $\zeta_m(s)$ has positive coefficients from that form. Am I supposed to multiply everything out to see it? I would really appreciate if you could add more details to your answer. Thanks

Comment: @JhonDoe Yes, you multiply it out.  You have a product of things whose coefficients are all positive, so the result will have positive coefficients. If you can show that for the product of two things, the general statement follows by induction.

Comment: Thanks again. But what is e(p). And what are the coefficients you are talking about? Are you talking about the coefficients of $(1+p^{-f(p)s}+..)$ in which case are the coefficients 1? or are you talking about the coefficients of $L(s,\chi)$. Thanks again.

Comment: $e_p$ is the multiplicity of $p$ occurring in $n$.  You are really overthinking this lol.  Write $X = p^{-s}$.  You are adding and multiplying a bunch of terms involving $X$.  There is no possible way you will ever get anything negative showing up